# "PHP exec return trimmed command."

Tags: php, uipath

I need to run a command line from PHP :

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-19.7.0\UiRobot.exe /file:"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\UiPath\TESTSMI\Main.xaml

but exec was already trimmed the above command.

background research :

```php
<?php
    exec('C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-19.7.0\UiRobot.exe /file:"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\UiPath\TESTSMI\Main.xaml"');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your UiRobot syntax wrong, the parameter is -file (as it says everytime when you run the robot with the command line you provided)

Assuming your paths are correct this will work:

```
<?php
exec('C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-19.7.0\UiRobot.exe -file:"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\UiPath\TESTSMI\Main.xaml"');
?>
```